# Insert multiple checkbox with different value into corresponding database column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple checkbox with different value into corresponding database column.

For example:

View:

I have 4 checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approverAccess[]" value="LA" >
<input type="checkbox" name="approverAccess[]" value="OA" >
<input type="checkbox" name="approverAccess[]" value="PC" >
<input type="checkbox" name="approverAccess[]" value="TS" >
```

And the table is something like this:

[image]

So the scenario is, If the first checkbox is checked, C1 column will have a value of '1' and the rest is '0', if second checkbox is checked C2 column will have a value of '1' and the rest is '0' and so on. Whatever checkbox is check it should be show or add in the corresponding table column.

Controller:

```
foreach($approverAccess as $selected) {     
    // ***What I'm going to do here****  
}

$data = array(
'ID' => '',
'USERID' => $adminID,
'C1' => $selected,
'C2' => $selected,
'C3' => $selected,
'C4' => $selected

);

$this->dbquery->modInsertval('tblapprover',$data);
```

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: Why not just name them `approverAccessC1`, `approverAccessC2`, `approverAccessC3`, and `approverAccessC4`?  In this case, I'm not sure using an array really provides any benefit.

Comment: *The table is something like this:* what is a *table* in this context

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array(
    'ID' => '',
    'USERID' => $adminID,
    'C1' => in_array('LA', $approverAccess) ? 1 : 0, 
    'C2' => in_array('OA', $approverAccess) ? 1 : 0,
    'C3' => in_array('PC', $approverAccess) ? 1 : 0,
    'C4' => in_array('TS', $approverAccess) ? 1 : 0
);

$this->dbquery->modInsertval('tblapprover',$data);
```